# Getting an address and creating a static google map in php

Tags: php, google-maps

Hi I have an address which has each line separated by tags e.g. span or p's I have used jQuery to strip out the tags (my idea is to get the address in a entire row) and then use google maps static version to link the address to the correct map, when I copy the google maps code and the address and paste that into google maps its fine and works as it should (ie it brings up the right map) but I need to take it one step further and show it as a image, If I wrap the code in a image tag like:

```
<img src='<?php function to bring address ?>' alt='' />
```

and then I go to preview it, It shows the tags I previously stripped out in jquery when I view the source of a image.

Can anyone shed any light on this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://imagine-it.org/google/staticmap/encodemymap.php and
http://static-maps-generator.appspot.com/